# Read continuously?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I'm working on senior project and I'm trying to use this code to read from TCP socket but it reads from the socket once a time,but I need a continuous readings

Any hints
Thanks in advance!
This is the code:

```
class ClientAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   String result = null;
   try {

    Socket socket = new Socket(params[0],
      Integer.parseInt(params[1]));

    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

    out.println(params[2]); 

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(is));
    //Read data in the input buffer
    result = br.readLine();
    //Close the client socket
    socket.close();
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return result;
  }
```

Comment: you know what is a while statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a loop for forever cycle? before you close socket with method

```
        socket.close()
```

Because in official documentation:
[Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close())

> Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound).

Comment: thanks for your responceI tried this one but still not working

Comment: while(true){
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
   
    out.println(params[2]); 
    //Buffer the data coming from the input stream
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(is));
    result = br.readLine();
   
    }